# Why defined?(var) is not recommended way to test optional locals in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html#label-Passing+local+variables+to+sub+templates),

> If you need to find out whether a certain local variable has been assigned a value in a 
>   particular render call, you need to use the following pattern:
>
> ```
> <% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
>   Headline: <%= headline %>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> **Testing using defined? headline will not work.** This is an implementation restriction.

But when I tested it in my Rails projects, the `defined?` test worked just fine.
Could anyone explain, what exactly the restriction is and when it gets triggered?

Comment: the diff is you have a Rails 3 app

Comment: and you're reading Rails 4 documentation

Comment: @apneadiving, you're right, but the test in Rails 4 project didn't change the behavior for me. Also this part of docs was the same [in Rails 3](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html#label-Passing+local+variables+to+sub+templates)